# wpl_cli :not found with rooted android device?

Tags: android, linux, wifi, wireless, android-wifi

i rooted my android device then i go to **adb shell**, then type `su` to enter `wpa_cli`.
 i surprise that this appeared : `wpa_cli: not found` although i get information when i type : `wpa_supplicant`?

i know that `wpa_cli` from same library `wpa_supplicant`? 

 from this [link](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dir_4b5a81f4cd4d61143d67145bf49b62e1.html)

android is linux based!! so why these commands can't be found in their kernel ?

Answer (score 0):

Because wpa_supplicant is not a library, it's an executable. Brief introduction is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant‎ and source code is here: https://github.com/android/platform_external_wpa_supplicant

Yes, wpa_cli is built from the same code base, but is not included on most phones. Android uses the wpa_crl.c/wpa_ctrl.h interface, not the command line utility wpa_cli.

The kernel doesn't contain commands and executables invoked through a shell.